# Windows Service run only on restarting computer

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have created a windows service which I would like to run whenever Windows starts. To run it after boot completion only, I have inserted below code in installer of service:

```
this.WinSvcInstaller.DelayedAutoStart = true;
```

The service is made to run immediately after installation using below code:

```
private void WinSvcInstaller_AfterInstall(object sender, InstallEventArgs e)
{
   ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(ServiceName);
   sc.Start();
}
```

where `ServiceName` is property created in WinSvcInstaller.

Once the service completed whether successfully or unsuccessfully it made to stop using below code automatically:

```
ProjectInstaller projectInstaller = new ProjectInstaller();
ServiceController serviceController = new ServiceController(projectInstaller.ServiceName);
if (serviceController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
    || serviceController.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.StartPending))
{                    
    this.Stop();
}
```

My main problem is that the service doesn't run unless I reboot computer meaning, the service runs only if I restart the computer. If I do shut down and then start computer manually again after the shut down then the service doesn't run. Can anybody please help me why is this happening??? What I am missing?

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer: There is no error in Event Viewer or any error is logged from service, if thats what you mean.

Comment: Try changing the service startup type from "Automatic (Delayed Start)" to "Automatic" and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: Start up type has only 3 options: Automatic, Manual, Disabled. However there is there is a separate Boolean option for DelayedAutoStart and it is set to True as mentioned in my question.

Comment: I meant using the Services administrative tool.  Equivalently, try turning DelayedAutoStart off.

Comment: @HarryJohnston, in Services Administrative too, it shows Start up as "Automatic (Delayed Start)". Also if I turn off it then would it affect boot performance? Anyway I will try that too and let you know what happens.